# I am trying to create SABRE SpecialServiceRQ with knownTravelerNumber and the documentation is not helpful

Tags: sabre, sabredav

```
<SpecialServiceRQ Version="2.1.1" xmlns="http://webservices.sabre.com/sabreXML/2011/10" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<SpecialServiceInfo>
    <SecureFlight>
        <PersonName DateOfBirth="1945-02-17" NameNumber="1.1">
            <GivenName>JAYDEN</GivenName>
            <Surname>MOORE</Surname>
        </PersonName>
        <VendorPrefs>
            <Airline/>
        </VendorPrefs>
    </SecureFlight>
    <Service SSRCode="DOCO">
        <PersonName NameNumber="1.1"/>
        <VendorPrefs>
            <Airline Code="NK"/>
        </VendorPrefs>
    </Service>
</SpecialServiceInfo>
```

and I keep getting wrong version response, Does the SpecialServiceInfo has to be some kind of list? do I need to separate Service and SecureFlight to separate SpecialServiceInfo nodes? I'm just lost

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems version 2.1.1 is not published yet. 2.1.0 does work.

Additionally, note that Service@SSRCode is not correct. It should be Service@SSR_Code.

Comment: 2.2.1 is published for SpecialService, but pointing the SSRCODE was good one. Thanks.